# Keep running web AJAX call in Android browser minimized

Tags: javascript, android, ajax

I have a simple AJAX call

```
var tid = setInterval(mycode, 2000);
function mycode() {
            $.ajax({
                url:'/ajx.php',
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                },
            }); 
}
```

I want it to keep running even when Android browser is minimized.
Currently It works only when browser is opened on screen.

If other browser other than Chrome/Mozilla can keep it running?

Comment: Put simply, you can't. It's a very purposeful restriction of all browsers to prevent battery drain and abuse. There are usually alternative solutions to the actual functional requirement you are trying to achieve, but you'd need to tell us more about what the reason is you think you need this and what the user goal is.

Comment: @adsy Actually I have to track user location with google API

Comment: It's not possible with a web application. The only way to do that in the background is to have a native application where the user has also permitted background updates for that app. Best you can do is update location when the page opens again. These restrictions are purposeful. Whilst I trust your intentions are good, imagine if any page you opened could know where you are....it' a security feature to prevent the (unfortunately many) bad actors.

Comment: No no.. It will run only if user allow to share his location

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, in the context of a webpage, even if the user allowed the page to access location -- it is unable to access it when the browser is closed. That privilege is reserved for native apps.

Comment: If you have a web app already, you could always consider adding this as a native only feature -- and deploying a native app that wraps your web app. For example, by using https://cordova.apache.org/.

Comment: I know PHP Javascript only. You mean I can create android app in cordova?

Comment: By the way I realise this answer is probably really frustrating for you right now -- I've been there! Yes, cordova basically allows you to create a native app whilst only really knowing web technologies. Its good in that the skills barrier is lower, but also apps that use it tend to feel a bit "fake", because its really a browser accessing your site. Wether it's good enough depends on your situation. However, it has the escalated privileges of a native app and the JS code can call into native functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  First off, when in the background even Services in Android only have a limited time to execute (they'll be killed after two minutes).  But you won't be in a Service-  you'll be in an Activity.  Activities generally cancel all timers and threads when they go into the background.  And even if they don't, they'll be killed themselves for resources very quickly.

Basically, what you want isn't how Android works.  You could get closer to this with an actual app (instead of just a browser page) and a foreground service, but even then you'd eventually be killed.  And even then you wouldn't work if the phone screen was turned off and the phone goes into Doze (a power saving mode where apps are only allowed a brief chance to execute every 15 minutes).

The best way to do this on Android is not to poll at all.  Polling a server constantly is considered an anti-pattern even for a website, it's the least efficient way of doing things in terms of CPU time, electricity cost on client and server, and your own network costs.  Instead, look into web sockets (or push messaging for a native app) and use that instead to notify the client when there's new data rather than forcing the client to constantly check if there's new data.  And with push messaging you can get around the whole Doze mode issue, as high priority push messages bypass Doze.